# Arg view == some other TextView

Tags: java, android

I would like to check if the argument TextView that's comming in is the same as the a TextView that holds an int.

```
public void threePlus(View view){
    if(view == findViewById(R.id.team_a_score)){
    scoreTeamA += 3;
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);}
    else{
        scoreTeamB += 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }
}
```

What would the proper way to obtain the View value to compare with? I tried findViewById(R.id.team_a_score) and `runs through the else statement` even when the incoming TextView is team_a_score.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be comparing the id's of the views; as `view.getId() == R.id.team_a_score`.

Comment: It still runs through the else statement no matter what.

Comment: Cannot resolve getId()? That means you're not using the Android View class.

Comment: I am, it's just still running through the else statement instead.

Comment: That means the view's id isn't team_a_score. Where are you setting that id? I'll need to see more of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I made the view variable to compare with:

`TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);`
then did the .getId() function with that and compared it with the argument .getId()

Here is the corrected code:

```
    public void twoPlus(View view){
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);

    if(view.getId() == scoreView.getId()){
        scoreTeamA += 2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);}
    else{
        scoreTeamB += 2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }
}
```